# How do you write to azure with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, azure

You'd think this would be the same as on-prem, but it doesn't appear to be.

Writing works fine like so (lifted from [microsoft's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-pandas?view=sql-server-ver16)):

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
server = 'myserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'mydatabase'
username = 'DefinitelyNotAdmin'
password = 'DefinitelyNotPassword'   
driver= 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sqlcmd = "SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM information_schema.tables"
df = pd.read_sql(sqlcmd, cnxn)
```

So far, so good. You can get the data out.

...but when you try and put the data back:

```
df.to_sql('test',cnxn,schema = 'lz')
```

You get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' 
AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. 
(208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) 
could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

When you follow microsoft's guide, it takes you to [Insert Python dataframe into SQL table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

which isn't pandas.

**Question:** How do you write a pandas dataframe to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

It works with Active Directory Integrated Authentication, which requires the MS Online widget:

```
conn_str = (
r'Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;'
r'Server=myserver.database.windows.net;'
r'Database=mydatabase;'
r'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;'
r'Trusted_Connection=No;')

quoted_conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_conn_str))
```

[MS Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-msonlinev1?view=azureadps-1.0) can be installed with this powershell command:

```
Install-Module -Name MSOnline
```